# Creating a low-s ECDSA signature in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, hyperledger-fabric, ecdsa

I need to interact with Hyperledger Fabric in an iOS application, and I've run into a problem when creating the proposal signature. Fabric requires low-s ECDSA, but I can't find a way to specify that in Apple's crypto functions. Without specifying low-s, my calls fail about %50 of the time, when S is higher than R.

My signing code is pretty simple:

```
  static func sign(data:Data, withPrivateKey:SecKey) throws -> Data {
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard
      let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(
        withPrivateKey,
        .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256,
        data as CFData,
        &error
      ) as Data?
    else {
      throw error!.takeRetainedValue()
    }
    return signature
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment in Hyperledger Fabric code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v2.2.13/internal/cryptogen/csp/csp.go#L101-L108), the "low-S" form of the ECDSA signature is the one described in [BIP-146](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0146.mediawiki#low_s), that is, `s < n/2`, where `n` is the order of your curve. Having just s < r is not enough.

You can transform a signature into "low-S" form yourself: parse the signature into `(r, s)`, flip it if needed (`s' = min(s, -s % n)`), and encode the result `(r, s')` back into bytes. The X9.62 point encoding is [not hard to parse](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185520/what-is-the-format-of-an-x9-62-key), and since signatures are public, you need not worry about leaking secrets through side channels.